# How to transform flutter BLoC stream snapshot into custom object?

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I'm trying to implement BLoC pattern in my flutter app,
basically this app calculate some result and display it in table.
i have created `CalculationResultProvider` and `CalculationResultBloc`
as follows

> ```
> class CalculationResultProvider 
> {   
> List<EstimationResult> resultList = new List();
>
>   List<EstimationResult> calculateResult(){
>     return getInitialData();   }
>
>   List<EstimationResult> getInitialData(){
>         var cement = new EstimationResult();
>         cement.material = "Cement";
>         cement.unit = "Ton";
>         cement.qty = 10;
>
>         var sand = new EstimationResult();
>         sand.material = "Sand";
>         sand.unit = "Ton";
>         sand.qty = 12;
>
>         var gravel = new EstimationResult();
>         gravel.material = "Gravel";
>         gravel.unit = "Ton";
>         gravel.qty = 5;
>
>         var steel = new EstimationResult();
>         steel.material = "Steel";
>         steel.unit = "Ton";
>         steel.qty = 5;
>
>         List<EstimationResult> resultList = new List();
>         resultList.add(cement);
>         resultList.add(sand);
>         resultList.add(gravel);
>         resultList.add(steel);
>
>         return resultList;    }  }
> ```

and my BLoC provider class as follows

```
class CalculationResultBloc {
  final resultController = StreamController(); // create a StreamController
  final CalculationResultProvider provider =
      CalculationResultProvider(); // create an instance of our CounterProvider

  Stream get getReult =>
      resultController.stream; // create a getter for our stream

  void updateResult() {
    provider
        .calculateResult(); // call the method to increase our count in the provider
    resultController.sink.add(provider.resultList); // add the count to our sink
  }

  void dispose() {
    resultController.close(); // close our StreamController
  }
}
```

then i need to show this data in table widget

```
class ResultTableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ResultTableWidgetState();
}

class ResultTableWidgetState extends State {
  final bloc =
      CalculationResultBloc(); // create an instance of the counter bloc

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.getReult,
        initialData: CalculationResultProvider().getInitialData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          DataTable(
            columns: [
              DataColumn(label: Text('Patch')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Version')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Ready')),
            ],
            rows:
                '${snapshot.data}' // Loops through dataColumnText, each iteration assigning the value to element
                    .map(
                      ((element) => DataRow(
                            cells: <DataCell>[
                              DataCell(Text(element[
                                  "Name"])), //Extracting from Map element the value
                              DataCell(Text(element["Number"])),
                              DataCell(Text(element["State"])),
                            ],
                          )),
                    )
                    .toList(),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

To iterate returning table it should be `List<EstimationResult>`

but how to transform snapshot in to `List<EstimationResult>` ?

where is the best place to transform inside bloc class or in widget class ?

im new to dart and flutter , can any one answer my questions?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your widget class will have no clue of the data type given by the stream function in your `StreamBuilder`, there are many ways to convert data in `BloC` right before streaming it, but all of them will be useless because to the widget class it's only a `snapshot`, and the only fields you can access in compilation time are those applied to a generic snapshot like `data` field. So, The only way to access custom list fields is to provide your `StreamBuilder` with what type of data to be expected from its `stream` function :

```
  StreamBuilder<List<EstimationResult>>(
    stream: bloc.getReult,
    initialData: CalculationResultProvider().getInitialData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
     //...
    }
  );
```

This way you can treat your `snapshot` as `List<EstimationResult>`, and have access to inner fields and functions right before you receive the actual snapshot. In your case probably you should import `EstimationResult` class into your widget class.

Comment: Thank you , Is there any best practices to achive my goal?

Comment: Well, I don;t know much about `DataTable` , maybe reading about how to populate them will give you an idea.

Comment: I have implemented your solution , but thing is how to convert snapshot.data to list , pardon me if im asking same thing again and again ,